# Unity Network update gameobject transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

Hey I'm new to Unity3D networking!

When I spawn my weapon (prefab) I would like to notify to all clients its transform setting (position, rotation, parent, etc...) so that it will attach to the player with correct values.

The problem is that only the host is aware of all changements, and for other clients only the local player (himslef) is updated.

I'm not sure if I'm using the Command and ClientRpc attributes correctly ^^'
here is the code:

```
void Start()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
        CmdSpawnGun();
}

[Command]
void CmdSpawnGun()
{
    GameObject gunPref = Resources.Load("Prefabs/GunPrefab") as GameObject;
    if (gunPref == null)
        Debug.Log("Failed to load Gun Prefab.");

    GameObject gun = Instantiate(gunPref, _weaponSlot);
    gun.GetComponent<Weapon>().Equip(this);

    NetworkServer.Spawn(gun);
    RpcNotifyTransform(gun, gameObject);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcNotifyTransform(GameObject block, GameObject rootIdentity)
{
    Transform slot = rootIdentity.GetComponent<Character>()._weaponSlot;
    if (slot == null)
        Debug.Log("Weapon slot not found.");

    block.transform.parent = slot;
    block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    block.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: how many clients are connected?